# Retrieving the bound value of a spinner

Tags: android, spinner, selected

I want to get Selected Value of a spinner.

First, I created a `STRING-ARRAY` in res/values/string

```
<string-array name="location">
    <item name="AUH">ABU DHABI</item>
    <item name="AAN">AL AIN</item>
    <item name="DMM">DAMMAM</item>
</string-array>
```

Spinner Definition in Layout:

```
<Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spnOrigin"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:entries="@array/location"/>
```

Now I need to complete the button click body, if user selects ABU DHABHI, he should return AUH.

`GETSELECTITEM` returns ABU DHABI, not the value behind this.  If I try something like this, can this approach allow me to get NAME attribute?

```
String[] _location =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.location);
```

Button Handler:

```
bttProcess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
    public void onClick(View v) {    

});
```

Comment: If you are going to have a lot of cities, it might be best to store the city name and three letter code in a SQLiteDatabase.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the name attribute is valid on [items of a string array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray).

I think your best bet is to set up another array to have the values in it. You can do `((AdapterView)getViewById(R.id.spnOrigin)).getSelectedItemPosition()` then look up the relevant name from that other array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the [exemple](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) in the android developer website to get started using spinner

First your activity have to  implement `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`. This will provide a callback method that will notify your application when an item has been selected from the Spinner.

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener
```

Second you need to register for the interface implementation by calling:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Finally within "onItemSelected" method of that class, you can get the selected item:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
    // Do nothing.
}
```

use your string array like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="locations">
        <item>ABU DHABI</item>
        <item>AL AIN</item>
        <item>DAMMAM</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: This did not return the `name` attribute for me.

Comment: @Sam I have already used this, and it's working for me. You should have missed something!!

Comment: If you use the author's String-Array and select the second item, is `String selected` equal to `"AL AIN"` or `"AAN"`?

Comment: k_Anas: how could it returns Value behind the item?

Comment: @nalaiqChughtai wich value the name of the country?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario where Spinner need to bind by KEY - VALUE PAIR List, 
The spinner can be get values from 
1. DATABASE 
2. An static String Array.
3. By creating Bi- Resource String Array.

FOR 3rd Point:
If you need to bind spinner by resource String Array, u need to create two array. One which will hold KEY [NAMES Of Countries], Second Will contains VALUES [Short Code of Countries].

Than on Click Button,

```
bttProcess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          

   public void onClick(View v) {    
    int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

    Log.i("Code:","Selected Country Code: "+
    getStringFromArray(R.array.locations_code, position ));

});

private String getStringFromArray(int id, int index) {
   try {
        String[] bases = getResources().getStringArray(id);
        return bases[index];
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

RESOURCES would look like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="locations">
        <item>ABU DHABI</item>
        <item>AL AIN</item>
        <item>DAMMAM</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="locations_code">
        <item>ABU</item>
        <item>AL</item>
        <item>DAM</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```